# How to refresh an EasyTabs tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins

I am using the jQuery plugin EasyTabs. As you see, I have a button to send json data to the tab, so the tab must refresh by ajax when the button is clicked, but in my case it only appends the path at the end but does not refresh the page.

I have something like this as a menu:

```
<a class="tab-feed-filter-switch active bound" href="/buzz/view/feed/keyword?id=70&amp;dataType=all" data-target="#filter-all">All</a>
```

And I have a button to append the new path for the tab:

```
    $('#Cusfeed').click(function(){
                var starttext = $('#start').val();
                var endtext = $('#end').val();

                var SatDateArray = new Array();
                SatDateArray = starttext.split("/");
                for(var x=0; x < SatDateArray.length;x++){
                }

                var EndDateArray = new Array();
                EndDateArray = endtext.split("/");
                for(var x=0; x < EndDateArray.length;x++){
                }

                var start = SatDateArray[2]+SatDateArray[0]+SatDateArray[1];        
                var end = EndDateArray[2]+EndDateArray[0]+EndDateArray[1];



                $.ajax({
                  url: '/buzz/view/feed/keyword?profileId=' + profileId + '&startDate='+ start +'&endDate='+ end,//getting the api
                  type: 'get',
                  success: function(data){ 

                  }

                });

                //appending href

                $('a.tab-feed-filter-switch').each(function(){
                    var href = $(this).attr('href') + '&startDate='+ start +'&endDate='+ end;
                    $(this).attr('href', href);
                    $('.a.tab-feed-filter-switch').tabs('load', 0);
                });
```

Update 1:
i tried to insert the answer given below in my onclick function:

```
 $('#Cusfeed').click(function(){

                    var starttext = $('#start').val();
                    var endtext = $('#end').val();

                    var SatDateArray = new Array();
                    SatDateArray = starttext.split("/");
                    for(var x=0; x < SatDateArray.length;x++){
                    }

                    var EndDateArray = new Array();
                    EndDateArray = endtext.split("/");
                    for(var x=0; x < EndDateArray.length;x++){
                    }

                    var start = SatDateArray[2]+SatDateArray[0]+SatDateArray[1];        
                    var end = EndDateArray[2]+EndDateArray[0]+EndDateArray[1];


                    $('a.tab-feed-filter-switch').each(function(){
                        var href = $(this).attr('href') + "&startDate="+start+"&endDate="+end;
                        $(this).attr('href', href);
                    });

                        var tab = $('.a.tab-feed-filter-switch').easytabs('getSelected');
                        tab.panel('refresh');
                });
```

But it doesn't seem like allowing me to use the .tabs fucntion. It returns **Uncaught TypeError: tab.panel is not a function**, it this an illegal way to apply it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tab = $('.a.tab-feed-filter-switch').tabs('getSelected');
tab.panel('refresh');
```

Comment: I tried to put these code in a onclick function but it returns error : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function